# Talking about the football

Tags: sentence-construction, british-english

I want to say:

> In this season, we can expect to see wonderful footballs from the team X. ( And I hope to see ...)

I have wrote below sentences. (Here, football means soccer, suppose Manchester United)

1. > We can expect **[ Adjective ? ]** football plays from the X.

I assumed that "football play" is a acceptable compound name (I am not sure).

2. > we can expect them to play **[adverb]**

Q1 : If the sentences are fine, I want to know which adjective or adverb is preferable to put them in the sentences. I came across with:

Wonderful - fabulous - great - astonishing - fascinating
and corresponding adverbs of these adjectives.

Q2 : If all the sentences sound odd or awkward, I will be happy to see your suggestion.

For example: Consider a conversation between me and my friend:

> "Did you see last night match against new-castle?"
>
> "Yes, they present a fabulous football. I think we can expect them to play magnificently this season."

Comment: What about the football play do you think will be "wonderful, fabulous, or astonishing"? Those **don't** sound like very suitable words to me, but, you've given no indication of what you are trying to express, so I'm hard pressed to provide an alternative. Victor suggested _masterful_, which **is** a good word, but it means something very specific, so it might not say what you are trying to say.

Comment: @J.R. Consider a conversation between me and my friend : " Did you see last night match against new-castle ? yes, they present a fabulous football. I think we can expect them to play magnificently this season "

Comment: Newcastle is the name of a football club and the city in which it is from, it should not be hyphenated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I am not sure you need to use the word "football" in a sentence about expected performance of Manchester United (or other team) if the entire article is about football.

> We can expect great <strike>football</strike> performance from Arsenal.

Second, since the meaning of all those adjectives you enumerated differs slightly, it falls on you to pick the right one to express the correct *shade* of the idea.

In addition to the ones you already found, here is a few more: **masterful**[**ly**], **brilliant**[**ly**], **superb**[**ly**], **extraordinary**[-**rily**].  Also check the synonyms for those to compile a fuller/more complete list.

Comment: The problem is I have no Idea about the slight difference between them. I provide a short conversation at comment as an example. I hop it can help you imagine what  is the situation.

Comment: @Cardinal: Yes, it certainly helps!  In a causal conversation like that the slight differences in meanings of those words **do not matter in the least**.  Use them all interchangeably.  Well, except perhaps the 'masterfully' that J.R. singled out.  If you find new words, look them up and try [for a day] to use them as you understand they should be used.  See people's response, ask them about their reaction to your use of those words.  Interaction is a better teacher than books and web.

Answer (score 3):

> *Yes, they present a fabulous football*.

That is not idiomatic English at all. I think most people would say something more like this:

> Yes, they played a great game.

---

> *I think we can expect them to play magnificently this season*.

This one isn't too bad. Even your choice of adverb is acceptable.

<sub>This next part will be hard to explain, but I'll give it a shot.</sub>

When talking about the team play, I would generally avoid these adjectives:

> fabulous, wonderful, astonishing, fascinating

They simply sound too flowery to describe the play of a football (soccer) team, in most contexts. (You might get away with *fabulous* or *astonishing* if you were talking about a team that played with remarkable skill in a very flashy way – but I don't think you'd see that very often.)

Then there are words like these, which are more common for this sort of thing:

> amazing, spectacular, sensational

However, in the context of sports, words like these are usually reserved for one particular play (*a [spectacular goal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9KwmOez4mc), an [amazing save](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9S5tVIe0rk)*, some [*sensational passing*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wivErkWTiNc) for example), rather than describing how one team played through the entire match.

If you want to talk about the strength of one team, rather than using a generic adjective like *wonderful* or *dazzling*, people talking about sports might be more apt to use phrases like these:

> I think they will be *tough to beat* this season.
>   I think they will *win a lot of games* this season.
>   I expect they will *play strong* all season long.